# How to add auto page break and footer per page in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, jspdf

How to add page break automatically when the page will be printed, I use jspdf plugin in vuejs 2, is it possible to add page break using those plugins?

Currently, the 2nd div appears broken in the exported file hence I would like to have the div and footer will appear from the next page.

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.final-proof-container {
  width: 1296px;
  height: 775px;
  /* background-color: #e8e8e8; */
  border-top: 6px solid #383434;
  border-left: 6px solid #383434;
  border-right: 6px solid #383434;
  /* padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; */
  /* display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.final-proof-content {
  /* width: 330px; */
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: #474747;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  /* margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 4px; */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; */
  /* margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; */
  /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
}

.material-type {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-content {
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.right-content {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.right-content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.dimensions {
  list-style: none;
}
.option-logo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 12px;
}

.material-circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.final-proof-footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1296px;
}

.top-section {
  background-color: #303030;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.bottom-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 175px;
}
.logo {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #686767;
  border-top: 3px solid #686767;
  border-left: 3px solid #686767;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #686767;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.order {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #686767;
  border-top: 3px solid #686767;
  border-left: 3px solid #686767;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #686767;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.location {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #686767;
  border-top: 3px solid #686767;
  border-left: 3px solid #686767;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #686767;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.shipping {
  width: 26.8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 4px solid #686767;
  border-top: 3px solid #686767;
  border-left: 3px solid #686767;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #686767;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.order img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.location img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.shipping img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.text-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 0.1;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.order-type {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn color="primary" @click="generateReport">Generate</v-btn>

    <div ref="order_details">
      <div class="final-proof-container">
        <v-layout row wrap style="padding: 10px !important">
          <v-flex
            xs4
            md4
            lg4
            v-for="(item, index) in order.carts"
            :key="index"
            class="pa-0"
            style="margin-bottom: 10px !important"
          >
            <div class="final-proof-content" style="margin: 10px !important">
              <div class="left-content">
                <p>Product(s): {{ getSectionNo(item) }}</p>
                <p class="mb-1">Material Type:</p>
                <div class="materia-type mb-2">
                  <span>
                    <div
                      class="material-circle"
                      :style="`background-color:${item.material.material_type.color}`"
                    ></div>
                    {{ item.material.material_type.name }}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1">Dimensions:</p>
                <ul
                  v-if="Array.isArray(getDimensions(item))"
                  class="dimensions mb-2"
                >
                  <li
                    v-for="(dimension, key) in getDimensions(item)"
                    :key="key"
                  >
                    {{ dimension.section_no }} - W: {{ dimension.width }}"| H:
                    {{ dimension.height }}"
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="mb-1">Options:</p>
                <!--Addition of option list in table layout-->
                <table class="option-list" id="option-list">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img
                        src="/assets/img/price_point.png"
                        class="option-logo"
                        alt="Logo"
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td><p class="mb-1 pl-1">Price Point: 2/$4.00</p></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="option-list">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img
                        src="/assets/img/comments.png"
                        width="20"
                        height="15"
                        alt="Comments"
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <p class="mb-1 pl-1">
                        Comments/Text: "Thanks for Shopping"
                      </p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="option-list">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img
                        src="/assets/img/image.png"
                        width="20"
                        height="15"
                        alt="Logo"
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td><p class="mb-1 pl-1">Logo: logo.png</p></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="quantity-table mt-2">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img
                        src="/assets/img/qty.png"
                        width="21"
                        height="8"
                        alt="Quantity"
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td><p class="mb-2 pl-1">Quantity: 2</p></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>

              <div class="right-content">
                <!-- <img :src="item.product.img_path" alt="" /> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </div>

      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="final-proof-footer">
        <div class="top-section">
          <div style="margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 8px">
            ORDER # MEC_EO-150454_AbingstonStopNGas
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            <!-- PAGE <span style="margin-left: 8px">1</span> OF 1 -->
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            Designer: Ryan Strawn
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-section">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="/assets/img/ww.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="order">
            <div class="order-type">
              <img src="/assets/img/man.png" alt="" />
              <div style="margin-top: 12px">Ordered By</div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-content">
              <p>Johnboy VanSampson</p>
              <p>johnboy@cocacola.com</p>
              <p>720-555-5698</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="location">
            <div class="order-type">
              <img src="/assets/img/shop.png" alt="" />
              <div style="margin-top: 12px">Project</div>
              <div>Location</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-content">
              <p>Abington Stop N Gas</p>
              <p>Attn:Johnboy VanSampson</p>
              <p>1562 Hiltop Pallace Blvd.</p>
              <p>Swingtown, NJ 77895</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="shipping">
            <div class="order-type">
              <img src="/assets/img/car.png" alt="" />
              <div style="margin-top: 12px">Shipping</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-content">
              <p>Abington Stop N Gas</p>
              <p>Attn:Johnboy VanSampson</p>
              <p>1562 Hiltop Pallace Blvd.</p>
              <p>Swingtown, NJ 77895</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      order: {},
      htmlToPdfOptions: {
        html2canvas: {
          useCORS: true,
          scale: 2,
        },
        jsPDF: {
          //   unit: "px",
          format: "letter",
          orientation: "landscape",
        },
      },
    };
  },

  watch: {
    value(val) {
      this.order = val;
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    const vm = this;
    // vm.generateReport();
  },

  methods: {
    async generateReport() {
      const vm = this;
      const doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: "l",
        unit: "px",
        format: "letter",
        hotfixes: ["px_scaling"],
        compress: true,
      });
      doc.html(vm.$refs.order_details, {
        margin: 10,
        autoPaging: "slice",
        html2canvas: {
          scale: 0.8,
        },
        pagesplit: true,
        callback: function (doc) {
          doc.save("test.pdf");
        },
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

atm, I don't see any property or function to support page break when printing HTML element, you just can do it manually via `doc.addPage()`.

To add header and footer on each page, you can iterate each page of doc, then attach your header and footer to suitable position.

For example:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= doc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
  doc.setPage(i)
  doc.text('This is header', 10, 30)
}
```

Comment: How about if the card overlap on the first page it will automatically display on the 2nd page is that possible?

Comment: It's impossible with `jsPDF` at current version. But, there is an alternative solution you can try: `html2pdf`. This lib will capture your page and paste it into pdf file. It also supports some printing css like `page-break-inside`. However, it still has some limitations you should consider before switching to.

Comment: I already tried the html2pdf and based on my observation it will convert the HTML to the image.  Thank you for the suggestion and information. I will try another solution.